# Why does sending multiple http requests from a node server on my laptop distort internet access

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

I am trying to crawl some data from a website using nodejs, axios and cheerio, the code is structure like this

```js
async function scrape(url) {
  const categories = await scrapeCategories(url);
  const posts = await Promise.all(categories.map((urls => scrapePosts(urls)));
  return posts;
}

async function scrapeCategories(url) {
  const {data} = await axios.get(url);
  
  ...logic to get posts
  return urls;
}

function scrapePosts(urls) {
  return Promise.all(urls.map((url => scrapePost(url)))
}

async function scrapePost(url) {
  const {data} = await axios.get(url);
  
  ...logic to get post data
  return urls;
}

scrape(...).then(console.log)
```

But when ever I run it, it sends some of the requests and after about 100 requests, my internet connection shuts down and I have to restart my router for internet connection to resume. All devices on the network are unable to access the internet when this happens.

i have been even using setTimeout to delay requests by about 100ms still does not change anything. I do not understand what exactly is going wrong here.

Comment: Could be some anti-DDoS or anti-congestion measure implemented by your ISP

Comment: This has little to do with your javascript, but more with your router/modem/backbone/ISP/whatever. Something along the line is analyzing the traffic, and either crashing, or deliberately stopping everything.

Comment: I will have to check with another ISP again then. Thank You guys.